# If I buy Little Big Planet 2: Special Edition from Craigslist, will I still be able to use the "bonus content" offered from the Special Edition?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

Is this "bonus content" DLC? Does it use DRM? I've never bought a used PS3 game before.

Comment: Usually you won't, but I can't speak to this particular game. Usually you get a redemption code in the box which unlocks stuff on the PSN store for you. If that code has been used, then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: From what I can tell, the additional content is on the disc, so buying it used should be fine, although this is difficult to confirm.  Some of these things are also free patches to the base game (ie, Move support).

Comment: What exactly is craiglist? Auction site?

Comment: @JamesJiao - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craigslist

Answer (score 2):

A video of the contents of the special edition:

As you can see, there doesn't seem to be any redemption codes included in the box, which would indicate that the content is on the disc itself. This would suggest that buying a used game should allow you to play the additional content without issue.